# White square in SFML, but texture is loading fine

Tags: c++, scope, sprite, sfml

I have a DBObject that stores `media` (an `sf::Sprite`) and `mediaTexture` (an `sf::Texture`). This is my `DBObject::loadMedia()` function:

```
void DBObject::loadMedia() {
    myStream mediaStream(mediaPath);
    mediaTexture.loadFromStream(mediaStream);
    media.setTexture(mediaTexture);
    mediaInit = true;
}
```

These DBObjects are stored in a `std::vector`.

When I try to draw the sprite to the display, it is completely white, and apparently this is from the texture going out of scope. But I define the texture in the DBObject, so it should have a lifetime of the object... right?

However, when I make a NEW sprite in my main() function, and do `newSprite.setTexture(DBObj.mediaTexture)`, it is displayed fine, so the texture itself is loading fine, but something is happening to the sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [the white square problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem).

Basically, at some point, your object is copied but the copy constructor doesn't update the copied sprite texture to use the copied texture, and the original texture is destroyed so the copied sprite doesn't have a valid texture anymore. This can happens for example when your `std::vector` needs to allocate more memory and move/copy stuff around.

Comment: So what can I do to change it? Just keep updating the sprite with the texture constantly?

Comment: No, just when copied, using a custom copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I added a custom copy and now it works fine. :)